# How can you inject a swift dynamic framework into an app at runtime using the LLDB debugger and iOS simulator?

Tags: swift, objective-c, lldb

I would like to be able to declare global helper functions and types for use in assisting debugging and keep these in their own framework.

I have found that it is possible to load the framework using LLDB by executing the following.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import lldb

def __lldb_init_module(debugger, internal_dict):
    debugger.HandleCommand("command script add -f {0}.HandleCommand custom".format(__name__))
    debugger.HandleCommand("command alias swift expression -l Swift -O --")
    debugger.HandleCommand("command alias objc expression -l objc -O --")


def HandleCommand(debugger, command, result, internal_dict):
    target = debugger.GetSelectedTarget()
    process = target.GetProcess()
    error = lldb.SBError()
    process.LoadImage(lldb.SBFileSpec("/path/to/CustomCommandHelper.framework/CustomCommandHelper"), error)

    if error.fail:
        result.SetError(error)
    else:
        result.AppendMessage("custom command loaded")
```

referenced from `.lldbinit`

```py
command script import /path/to/CustomCommands.py
```

From the debugger typing the following will now load the framework into the debugger

```sh
(lldb) custom
```

However I am not able to access any of the types with in it except by [ab]using objc

```swift
@objc public class TestClass2: NSObject {
    public override init() {}

    @objc public let text = "Test"
}
```

```sh
(lldb) objc id testClass2 = [[NSClassFromString(@"CustomCommandHelper.TestClass2") alloc] init]; [testClass2 text];
Test
```

```sh
(lldb) swift let testClass2 = CustomCommandHelper.TestClass2(); testClass2.text
error: <EXPR>:8:18: error: module 'CustomCommandHelper' has no member named 'TestClass2'
let testClass2 = CustomCommandHelper.TestClass2(); testClass2.text
```

Comment: May be try `expression import <yousr framework>`

Comment: Thanks @Cy-4AH I left that out of my question because it already seemed fairly code heavy.  I did try importing rather than referencing the module directly.  The import did not trigger an error but results are similar.

`(lldb) custom`
`custom command loaded`
`(lldb) swift import CustomCommandHelper`
`(lldb) swift TestClass2().text`
`error: <EXPR>:8:1: error: cannot find 'TestClass2' in scope`
`TestClass2().text`